# Stylus ink pressure is not working

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft.ink

I am trying to apply Ink capability to my Windows Store App.

Based on the [Simplified Ink Sample in MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-simplified-ink-sample-11614bbf) (note that I use C# sample),
I modified the 51st line in Scenario1.xaml.cs, `drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;` in order to use Stylus Pressure.

FYI, below part is the code block from line 46~52.

```
        // Initialize drawing attributes. These are used in inking mode.
        drawingAttributes = new Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkDrawingAttributes();
        drawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
        double penSize = 2 + 2*PenThickness.SelectedIndex;
        drawingAttributes.Size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(penSize, penSize);
        drawingAttributes.IgnorePressure = false;
        drawingAttributes.FitToCurve = true;
```

But the stroke thickness was not changed as I expected.
I added `drawingAttributes.PenTip = PenTipShape.Circle;` right after the 51st line but the pressure does not be affected.

Do I miss something?
My stylus is working properly with Fresh Paint app or other pressure-sensitive apps (I'm using Lenovo x230t tablet).

Answer (score 0):

The XamlInkRenderer in that sample ignores the DrawingAttribute.Pressure when drawing the strokes. Each stroke is drawn with constant width so even though the pressure is recorded it isn't used.

Comment: // Thanks for the reply. I was looking forward to get the reply. And then, how can I display various width stroke on that? Is there any other `XamlInkRenderer` example?

Comment: Not that I know of. [Project Austin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/11/10348466.aspx) has some C++ code for generating strokes with variable width but I haven't looked at porting it to C# yet.